# Laravel 5 - increase the speed of loading pages (Bootstrap modals)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

The speed of loading pages is 700ms on localhost and 1200-5000ms on live.
I guess that it could be due to Bootstrap modals. At about 10 Bootstrap modals are `@include()` - load - when entering the main page.

Is it possible to `@include()` right modal while clicking on the button calling them? Or is there another way to speed up page?

Comment: Did you install the Laravel debug bar? You could track down every timing you want with it like database query or even had your own timers to see if the rendering is too long. You could also load your modals on the fly with some ajax requests.

Comment: I didn't install `Laravel Debugbar`. I'll have to do. 

hmm... I wonder if loading modals by Ajax is a good solution?

Comment: It's not "bad" if you're asking but the problem might come from somewhere else so I would track this before using Ajax

Comment: It would make sense to use Ajax if you have very large DB requests to load your modals and they're not mandatory in the current page IMHO

Comment: Laravel debugbar is a must to develop with Laravel btw ;)

Comment: I think you should include only a modal scaffold and when you click the trigger element (which fire the open model event) you should send a backend request and you can pass the response to your modal.

Comment: I am not using `Laravel Debugbar`. It's not "a must to develop with Laravel".   It can be sometimes useful to use on your development environment system. Regarding the question, you should not load them all if you don't need them all, or try to reuse them as much as possible. Programatically define the fields in the modal according to your needs.